# Android Studio- creating new virtual device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I tried creating new virtual device but everytime I try to create it and click on 'finish', it shows 'Nothing Selected'.

[image]

Comment: you cannot click on finish?

Comment: When I click on finish, it shows "nothing selected"

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html go through this